# output for System.out.println gives strange number

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("1 + 2 = " + 1 + 2);
```

output: 12

can you explain why this is ? I tried to look through some documentation but did not find anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `+` operator works from left to right, it adds the string `"1 + 2 = "` to `1` first, and gets `"1 + 2 = 1"`, then adds `2` to get `"1 + 2 = 12"`.

It's equivalent to

```
System.out.println(("1 + 2 = " + 1) + 2);
```

Try this instead.

```
System.out.println("1 + 2 = " + (1 + 2));
```

Comment: i still dont see how we get 12

Comment: Because you've in reality appended the string `"1"` and then the string `"2"` to the existing string with `+`.  This behavior occurs when one operand of `+` is a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the left-hand operand is a `String`, then the left-hand operand gets cast to a `String`.

`"1 + 2 = " + 1` is evaluated first. The result is the String `"1 + 2 = 1"`. Then the next operation is `"1 + 2 = 1" + 2`. The result of that operation is `"1 + 2 = 12"`

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+` always groups from left to right.  So you get `"1 + 2 = " + 1`, (which gives `"1 + 2 = 1"`), and then the `2` gets added on last, giving `"1 + 2 = 12"`.

If you want it to group from right to left, you need to use parentheses, like `"1 + 2 = " + (1 + 2)` and this will give `"1 + 2 = 3"`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of priority. It goes from left to right, if you are using only `+`. First, the string `1 + 2 =` is created, then you add number to the string, resulting in string `1 + 2 = 1` and then you add next int to string resulting in string `1 + 2 = 12`.

You can avoid that by using brackets `"1 + 2 = " + (1 + 2)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Specification §15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

And [§15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).
>
> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.

So the first half, `"1 + 2 = " + 1`, is the first part to get evaluated. Because the first half of *that* is a String, it evaluates to: `"1 + 2 = 1"`. The whole expression is now `"1 + 2 = 1" + 2`. Once again, one of the two operands in this expression is a String, so the `+` operand concatenates. The whole expression then evaluates to the String `"1 + 2 = 12"`, which is then printed.